# Class of laravel package not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

I made a laravel package with this `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "calcanotica/file-storage",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A file storage module for laravel.",
    "homepage": "<<gitlab url>>",
    "authors": [
        {
            <<authors>>
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Calcanotica": "src" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.5.9 || ^7.0",
        "illuminate/contracts": "5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.*",
        "illuminate/support": "5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

The structure of the package is:

```
-src
   -Storage
      -S3FileStorage.php
```

In the `S3FileStorage.php` file I have the following class:

```
namespace Calcanotica\Storage;

class S3FileStorage { ... }
```

But, when I try to use the class inside another application as `\Calcanotica\Storage\S3FileStorage`, I get a `Class \Calcanotica\Storage\S3FileStorage not found` error.

I already execute `composer dump-autoload`.

What's the problem?

Comment: side note: most of your `require` entries makes no sense. Please read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md

Comment: thanks @MarcinOrlowski I would check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `autoload` section is incorrect. Namespace must end with `\\` ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4)) so it should be:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Calcanotica\\": "src" }
},
```

however I'd replace the whole

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Calcanotica": "src" }
},
```

with

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [ "src/" ]
},
```

and let composer figure out what is where ([docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap)), which in general use is better, less error prone than setting up namespace mapping by hand and won't require any future attention if you add new namespace to your package.

Comment: That worked! thanks. Could you give a brief explanation on why it wasn't working and now it does? or point to a reference...

Comment: perfect @MarcinOrlowski. Than you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` file add following lines :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Calcanotica\\": "src/"
    },

},
```

You need to add `\\` after your namespace and `/` after your `src`. For more check here : https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4